# limiting size of text file and creating a new one dynamically in java

Tags: java

I am writing some logs to a TXT file using file writer and I want to limit the size of the txt file to some value.
Once the limit is reached I want to create a new file dynamically.
Is there a way to do it in java?

Java code would be appreciated.

Comment: doesn't log4j or slf4j address this?

Comment: IF you are using some external logging frameworks like Log4J , you can set it in configuration file like RollerAppender

Answer (score 2):

Try to checking when your file exceed some lenght take an action and create new.

```
   long SOME_VALUE = 1000;
   String fileName = "test";
   int i=0;
   File file = new File(fileName+".txt");
   public void checkAndUpdateFile(){
        //do it in some loop or in some period of time

        if(file.length()>SOME_VALUE){
           file.close();
           file = new File(fileName + String.valueOf(i++)+".txt"); 
       }
    }
```

Comment: +1. Note: The file length returned by `file.length()` is measured in bytes.

Comment: Yes, this is number of bytes.